# XML serialization and "<" , ">" when generating an HTML document

Tags: c#, html, serialization, xmlserializer, xml-encoding

I'm trying to dynamically generate an HTML table by using `XmlSerializer` and a set of classes like this:

```
[XmlInclude(typeof(Th))]
public class Td
{
    [XmlElement("span")]
    public string Designation { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("colspan")]
    public int ColSpan { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute("rowspan")]
    public int RowSpan { get; set; }

    public Td(string designation, int colspan)
    {
        Designation = designation;
        ColSpan = colspan;
        RowSpan = 1;
    }

    public Td()
    {            
    }

}
```

The problem here is that the `Designation` property can have a tag as value like `<option...>`, so when I serialize my model I get `&lt;option...&gt;` instead of `<option...>`

I can solve the problem by using the `string.Replace` method like this: `Replace("&lt;", "<").Replace("&gt;", ">");`

Is there a clean way to get the expected result without the use of `string.Replace`?

Comment: XML != HTML. Most XHTML work has been discontinued, afaik.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create another property that exposes `Designation` as an `XmlNode`:

```
[XmlIgnore]
public string Designation { get; set; }

[XmlElement("span")]
public XmlNode DesignationAsXml
{
    get
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.InnerXml = "<root>" + this.Designation + "</root>";
        return doc.DocumentElement.FirstChild;
    }
    set
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException();
    }
}
```

Comment: How would Deserialization work here? A serialized object will not deserialize with the same information here.

Comment: @Nenotlep: The OP's scenario didn't require deserialization so I didn't bother implementing the property setter. To do so, simply assign `value.OuterXml` to `this.Designation` instead of throwing an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing it manually is needless.
 I think the best way is using `System.XML.XmlWriter.WriteString` class. Look for class definition [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2008/10/21/Different-ways-how-to-escape-an-XML-string-in-C.aspx)